# SQL - Select top 1 with according to values from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by, partitioning

I know the title doesn't say much, but let me explain you my situation:

I have the following table:

[image]

Now, I would like to select top 1 from each department, but I don't want to get duplicate position id, so I want the top employee from each department by number of projects, but distinct position ids. The results are the highlighted rows.

Comment: Is it possible that the second highlighted row is wrong? Shouldn't it be the one containing EmplyeeID 580824 DepID 484646 (which has 52 projects)? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: You right. I'm sorry. In this case EmplyeeID 580824 will be selected. I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that the returned positions will be the best.  One position might be the best in two departments, in which case, one of the results constraints will need to be relaxed.

So, here is a method to get some (perhaps all) departments with the highest ranking but distinct positions.  Start by choosing only the highest ranked employees for each department.  These are the one with the most projects.

Then, for each `PositionTypeId` choose a random department from among these alternatives.  Then, for each department, choose a random position type.  The following query takes this approach:

```
select DepID, EmplyeeID, PositionTypeId, NumProjects
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by DepId order by newid()) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by PositionTypeId order by newid()) as position_seqnum
            from (select t.*,
                         dense_rank() over (partition by DepId order by NumProducts desc
                                           ) as rank_seqnum
                  from t
                 ) t
            where rank_seqnum = 1
           ) t
      where position_seqnum = 1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is *not* guaranteed to return a row for each department.  But, it is guaranteed that all departments returned will have different position types and the rows will be best for that department.  You could probably work to tweak the middle step to ensure a greater coverage of departments.  However, because the problem is not guaranteed to have a solution, such tweaks may be more effort than they are worth.

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but it does the job. Thanks!!